# IOS application shows as grey box on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

We have inherited a 3rd party `iOS app` that needed to be re-signed. Its deployed to end-users via Microsoft Intune.

Because of this, we have set up an `iOS` developer license, etc..

The app works when I put it on my local device but not when deployed to intune.

Is this because I am missing the hundreds of `UDID's` in my developer account?

I appreciate this is very hard to try to `help/diagnose` with the limited information I have given but any `help/guidance` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an enterprise developer program membership?  If not then you cannot distribute an app directly to devices. If you have a normal, organisational program membership then you may be able to submit the app as a B2B private app so that Apple signs it and yo can then distribute it via InTune

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. I appreciatre you takign the time to reply.